# How to complete the quest: Every second counts?

Tags: anno-2070

I'm stuck at the Every second counts quest (chapter 2, mission 1). The game wants me to build a deep sea warehouse on the free site of the underwater island. But it says: "you can only have one deep sea warehouse per underwater island" and I don't have any other deep sea warehouses, so I'm pretty much stuck. What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build the [deep sea warehouse](http://anno2070.wikia.com/wiki/Deep_Sea_Warehouse), to do this you need to put the required materials (8 building modules and 4 tools) on a sub, submerge it and make it move to the underwater island, then the option to build the warehouse appears.

What the game means by

> You can only have one deep sea warehouse per underwater island

is that you can only have 1 deep sea warehouse on each underwater island.

Comment: Ahh... The resources are key. I thought the "You can only have one warehouse per island" message was due to an extra warehouse, not a lack or resources! Thanks!